# How do I display the zipped content in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, zip

While trying to map few variables using the zip function(return via a method), the result was displayed as:

```
<zip at 0x5f24990>
```

how do I display it's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the result in a `list`:

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]

zipped = zip(a, b)
list(zipped)
```

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```